# Find all usages of @ (supressed errors) in Intellij

Tags: php

I've just been scratching my head over a suppressed fatal error for the past day or so:

```
@this_method_causes_a_fatal();
```

Is there a plugin in Intellij or a standard way of me being able to find all usages of @ in a project so I can take them out?

If I search for just a space an @, I get variables in my docblock annotations in my search results, and there is alot of those, itd be nice if something just took me straight to the above.

Comment: Why the vote down, this is an incredible question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IntelliJ `Analyze > Run inspection by name...` and choose `Usage of silence operator`

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude comments when doing a search :

In the "find in path" box, there is a select named "context" choose "except comments and string literals" this way, the search will be performed only in your code

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this definitely reduces stuff I don't want to see, however this includes email addresses and git accounts in log files, composer etc. My accepted answer does the trick.